# Not-continuos map with its graph closed.

Tags: general-topology, functions, metric-spaces, graphing-functions

> Find an example of a map $f:(X,d_{X})\rightarrow (Y,d_{Y})$ between metric spaces such that $X$ is compact, $f$ is not continuous but $\Gamma(f):=\lbrace (x,f(x))\in X\times Y\mid x\in X\rbrace$ is closed in $X\times Y$

I though about this example:

$$f:([0,1],d_{e})\rightarrow ([0,1],d_{disc})$$

$$f(x)=x$$

Obviously, $f$ is not continuous because we have the discrete metric and $[0,1]$ is compact with the euclidean metric. So $\Gamma(f)$ is the bisector of first and third quadrant. Now, I have some problems to see if $\Gamma(f)$ is closed. I though about the fact that the discrete topology is stronger that the euclidean Topology so this bisector is closed. But I have some doubt because the product topology is particular in this case. Can someone help me? Thanks before!

Comment: Let $X=[0,1]$, note that $X_{eucl} \times X_{eucl} \rightarrow X_{eucl} \times X_{disc}$ is open, thus (it’s a bijection) closed. But $\Gamma(f)$ is closed in $X_{eucl} \times X{eucl}$...

Comment: The product topology is finer than the Euclidean topology on $[0,1]^2$, so every Euclidean open set is open in the product topology, and therefore every Euclidean closed set is closed in the product topology.

Comment: I thoufh also about the fact that a neighborhood of $(x,f(x))$ is $\mathcal{U}\times {f(x)}$ where $\mathcal{U}$ is a neighborhood of $x$ in [0,1] with the euclidean Topology, so if $(x,y)$ is a limit point for $\Gamma(f)$, there is a neighborhood $\tilde{U}\times {y}$ such that $(\tilde{U}\times {y})\cap\Gamma(f)\neq\emptyset$ but this implies that $y\in [0,1]$ with the discrete topology and so x=y. Is it right?